# How to restrict user from entering leading spaces and imojis in name field

Tags: flutter

I have name field in profile page. I want to restrict user from adding leading spaces. But in the process what I did is the user can't put any space now. I want him to simple enter "Arjun Malhotra"   and not "   space space space  Arjun Malhotra"......
This is the code

```
child: TextFormField(
                                                      inputFormatters: [
                                                        FilteringTextInputFormatter
                                                            .deny(
                                                                RegExp('[ ]')),
                                                      ],
                                                      maxLength: 20,
                                                      readOnly: !edit,
                                                      controller: name,
                                                      autovalidateMode:
                                                          AutovalidateMode
                                                              .onUserInteraction,
                                                      autofocus: true,
                                                      validator: (value) {
                                                        RegExp regex =
                                                            RegExp(r'^.{3,}$');
                                                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                                          return ("Name can't be empty");
                                                        }
                                                        if (!regex
                                                            .hasMatch(value)) {
                                                          return ("Name can't be empty");
                                                        }
                                                        if (value.trim() ==
                                                            "") {
                                                          return ("Name can't be empty");
                                                        }
                                                        if (value
                                                                .trim()
                                                                .length <=
                                                            2) {
                                                          return ("Minimum of 3 characters Required");
                                                        }
                                                        return null;
                                                      },
                                                      onSaved: (value) {
                                                        name.text = value!;
                                                      },
                                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                                        context
                                                            .read<
                                                                ProfileDetails>()
                                                            .name = value;
                                                      },
                                                      decoration:
                                                          InputDecoration(
                                                        counterText: "",
                                                        filled: true,
                                                        fillColor: const Color(
                                                            0xFFC2E3FE),
                                                        enabledBorder:
                                                            InputBorders
                                                                .enabled,
                                                        errorBorder:
                                                            InputBorders.error,
                                                        focusedErrorBorder:
                                                            InputBorders.error,
                                                        border:
                                                            InputBorder.none,
                                                        focusedBorder:
                                                            InputBorders
                                                                .focused,
                                                        contentPadding:
                                                            const EdgeInsets
                                                                    .only(
                                                                left: 30,
                                                                right: 10),
                                                        hintText: "Name",
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
```

Above code only allows this format "ArjunMalhotra". How can I achieve what I want and also I dont want user to add emojis. Is there a special keyboard type I need to specify or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^\s*`: This will match any (*) whitespace (\s) at the beginning (^) of the text

```
inputFormatters: [
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'^\s*')),
],
```